# WIN32アプリケーションプログラムでコンソール使うとランタイムエラーが出る

Tags: c++, winapi

使用OSはWindows10、症状はタイトルの通りです。
WIN32アプリケーションで、デバッグ目的でコンソールの表示、文字出力の処理を作りました。

が、ランタイムエラーがデバッグ実行した時のみ出ます。ランタイムエラーが出るタイミングはWinMain()を抜けたあとのext_common.inlの273行目、

```
 exit(main_result);
```

です。ランタイムエラーの内容は、

```
0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified
```

となっています。以下ソースコードです。

```
#include<io.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fcntl.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    int hConsole;
    FILE* pFile;

    if( AllocConsole() )
    {
        hConsole = _open_osfhandle( (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), _O_WTEXT);
        pFile = _fdopen(hConsole, "w");
        freopen_s( &pFile, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    }

    std::cout << "aaa" << std::endl;

    FreeConsole();
    return 0;
}
```

最後のFreeConsole()を呼ばなければエラーは出ません。
じゃあFreeConsole()呼ばなければいいという話なのですが、それは片付けをしていないので、それもどうなのかなという感じです。

デバッグ実行時にしか出ないので、デバッグ実行時はFreeConsole()か、それに該当する処理が勝手に走るということなのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 試してみようと思ったのですが、エラーが発生しませんでした。コンパイラのバージョンやターゲット(x86, x64)、コンパイラオプションなどを書いていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決策を一つ書きます。
上記のコードにはAllocConsole()で表示する2つの方法が混じって使われています。
ですが、それがエラーの本質的な原因ではありません。
ひとまずは下記コードで問題なく動くかと思われます。

```
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //int hConsole;   // DEL
    FILE* pFile;

    if (AllocConsole())
    {
        //hConsole = _open_osfhandle((long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), _O_WTEXT);   // DEL
        //pFile = _fdopen(hConsole, "w");   // DEL
        freopen_s(&pFile, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    }

    std::cout << "aaa" << std::endl;
    // Add Start
    Sleep(1000);  // DEBUG
    if (pFile != NULL)
    {
        fclose(pFile);
    }
    // Add End 
    FreeConsole();
    return 0;
}
```

しかし、_open_osfhandleを用いた方法ではご質問と同様のエラーが発生し、
解決策がわかりませんでした。

参考リンク
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020790/using-stdin-with-an-allocconsole